# file_get_contents - 500 ошибка

Tags: php

Здравствуйте. При вводе несуществующего сайта file_get_contents выдает 500 ошибку.

Вопрос : у меня список урлов, как можно отсортировать их на рабочие и нет, если выбивает 500 ошибку ?

Данная конструкция никак не помогает

```
$opts = array('http' => array(
    'method' => "GET",
    'header' => "User-Agent Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0\r\n"
    . "Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\r\n"
    . "Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate\r\n"
    . "Accept-Language:cs,en-us;q=0.7,en;q=0.3\r\n"
    . "Connection:keep-alive\r\n"
    ));
$context = stream_context_create($opts);
$link=file_get_contents("http://test12321434.ru/",false,$context);
```

Answer (score 1):

На основе ответов: [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/272361/how-can-i-handle-the-warning-of-file-get-contents-function-in-php) и [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15620124/http-requests-with-file-get-contents-getting-the-response-code).

Пытаемся получить содержимое страницы, `$content = @file_get_contents($site);`, символ `@`, если не нужно выводить `warning` предупреждения.

Далее проверяем смогли ли прочитать контент `if($content === FALSE) { // Здесь обрабатываем ошибку... }`

Если нужно заголовки проверить (на код 500 например), используем [глобальную переменную](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httpresponseheader.php) `$http_response_header`.

Как разделить ссылки уже сами решайте.

Хотя с cURL-ом мне кажется будет лучше выглядеть.

Привел пример ниже, как можно использовать все вышеописанное.

```
$urls = [
   'http://site1.ru',
   'http://site2.ru',
]

$badUrls = [];
$goodUrls = [];
foreach ($urls as $url) {
    $content = @file_get_contents($site); 
    if($content === FALSE) {
        //Здесь обрабатываем ошибку,
        //можно проверить заголовки из $http_response_header
        array_push($badUrls, url); 
    }
    else {
        array_push($goodUrls, url); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Но вы все как-то усложнили не по моему вопросу!

Интересует решение проблемы, касательно того, почему при добавлении нерабочей ссылки, я получаю 500 ответ

Comment: @Sarkis Allahverdian, тогда очень странный вопрос :-) получаете ответ 500 потому что ссылка не рабочая :-) Или имеете ввиду почему выдает ошибку 500 вместо того что-бы написать что адрес не резолвится dns-ом ?